# How to capture contents of line up to certain string?

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have this output:

```
Never logged in.
Last login Wed Jun 22 15:12 2016 (BST) on pts/11 from host1
```

I need it without the `(BST) on pts/11 from host1`
just like that:

```
Never logged in.
Last login Wed Jun 22 15:12 2016
```

my current command is `./lastlog.sh | xargs -n1 finger | grep -i 'Never\|Last'`

Comment: So essentially, you don't want to capture anything past a certain string(e.g. "(BST)"), right? Or do you just want to always capture HALF of the line, e.g. if the line is "Last christmas", you'd capture "Last ch"?

Comment: i dont want to capture anything past a certain string, which is the (BST)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
./lastlog.sh | xargs -n1 finger | grep -i 'Never\|Last' | sed -e 's/ (.*$//'
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ... | grep -Po '^.*(?=\(BST)|^.*'
```

- `-P` to use Perl regular expression functionality (more powferfull, gnugrep)
- `-o` to print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line
- `^.*(?=\(BST)` find a char sequence followed by `(BST` right lookahead
- `|`  or ...
- `^.*` any other char sequence

Comment: would you care to explain the expression ?

Comment: @Archemar, good idea ☺.

Answer (score 0):

```
./lastlog.sh | xargs -n1 finger | grep -i 'Never\|Last' | awk -F'(' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: i tried your command it did not work bass shukran anyway :-)

Comment: @Nick_baba wlc, but, not working ?? what is the output you got from my command ?

Comment: same output with this warning: awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
awk: warning: escape sequence `\)' treated as plain `)'

Comment: I edited it, can you try it now please ?